# displaying values in tabular format

Tags: java, list, jsp, arraylist, iteration

displaying List in tabular format but somewhere I am doing wrong.

### a.jsp

```
 List<String> abc = 
 (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("studentsrollno"); // got 
 studentsrollno from servlet by request.setAttribute();

 <form action="b.jsp" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="rollno" value="<%=abc%>"/>

        <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

### b.jsp

```
  <%

  String str[] = request.getParameterValues("rollno");
  List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();

  a1 = Arrays.asList(str);

  Iterator<String> itr = a1.iterator();


  %>

  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>roll no</th>
  </tr>

  <%while(itr.hasNext()){

   String s=(String)itr.next();

  %>

  <tr>
  <td>

  <%=s%>

  </td>

  </tr>

  <% }%>

  </table>
```

### Above table display output like

roll no

[1,2,3,10,34]

but I want to display output like table header and column 
 like below

```
 roll no
    1
    2
    3
    10
    34
```

Somewhere i am doing wrong in b.jsp , can anyone please point it out. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of your old question, because until you follow the solution in the answer to the old question and fix the generation of `<input>` fields in `a.jsp`, your values will always be wrong in `b.jsp`.

Comment: I found solution of my previous question but now only I need to display in tabular format , can u help me please

Comment: As I commented in a now-deleted answer: If the original `List<String> abc` is a list of 3 strings, e.g. `{ "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" }`, then the scriptlet `<%=abc%>` will use `toString()` to get `"[Foo, Bar, Baz]"`, and hence the value of input `rollno` will be that single string.

Comment: Maybe you found solution, but you haven't applied it to `a.jsp`, so `request.getParameterValues("rollno")` in `b.jsp` will get an array of length 1, no matter how many values were in the `abc` list in `a.jsp`. --- Which is why you see a single row with value `[1,2,3,10,34]`, just like I already said in previous comment.

Comment: ok I am getting ur point but there must be a way to display in tabular format ..i am trying to find out... so far unable to find..any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Ok please enlighten what modifications should i do in a.jsp? ur help will be much appreciated

Comment: If I keep iterator loop then I have to keep the form inside the loop and every time in every row submit button will arise which i don't want hence i am passing arraylist to b.jsp

Comment: @Andreas I request u to plz enlighten what  modifications should i do in a.jsp so that i can get the values in tabular format in b.jsp

Comment: Ok sorry i got it but instead of jstl in scriptlets please ... I am about to learn jstl...

Comment: value="${fn:escapeXml(item)}" /> I am not able to get it , hence scriptlets will be fine